# Squarespace CSS: When I target code for bordered columns to a section, the Mobile width shrinks to less than half of the screen

Tags: css, squarespace

Site URL: https://www.ukulelekidz.com/camp

Here is my desktop code for 2 column border with shadow (works good)

```
.sqs-col-6 {border: 2px solid #172236;width:47%!important;margin-left: 2.5%; box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)}
```

Here is my adjustment for mobile... (works good also)

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){ .sqs-col-6 {margin-left:0%!important;margin-bottom: 7%}}
```

The issue is the borders are applied to all 2 column sections on my site, so i then go to target just the section I want and great, it works for desktop, but then messes up the mobile view. Here is the full code i used to target the section:

```
section[data-section-id="6038f9680adafe73679299cc"]
.sqs-col-6 {border: 2px solid #172236;width:47%!important;margin-left: 2.5%; box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)}
@media only screen and (max-width:768px){ .sqs-col-6 {margin-left:0%!important;margin-bottom: 7%}}
```

See screen shot of what happens to mobile view when I target.

I did find a work around by not targeting the section, and then removing the border effect from where it appears on all other 2 column sections... Example:

```
section[data-section-id="60387a655347d0248f70c4ea"]{.sqs-col-6 {border: none; box-shadow:none}}
```

but I don't think that's how CSS should work. How do I target code for a desktop section in squarespace, then fix the code for mobile?

I am new to CSS so any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS, in place of what you have now, will add the border and box shadow at all widths, will separate the columns horizontally at wide widths, and will separate them vertically on mobile. The margin is split between left and right so that the boxes are centered.

```
#page-section-60387a655347d0248f70c4f4 .sqs-col-6 {
  border: 2px solid #172236;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #page-section-60387a655347d0248f70c4f4 .sqs-col-6 {
    width: 47.5% !important;
    margin-left: 1.25%;
    margin-right: 1.25%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #page-section-60387a655347d0248f70c4f4 .sqs-col-6 {
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
}
```